# Can I Sign IOS application without developer credentials?

Tags: xcode, ios, applet

I'm developing an IOS app for a client who got his IOS Developer Account and don't want to share the credentials, is there a way to sign that app without the credentials, I already got the certificate and provisioning profile but on the archiving stage the account is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No;  There is no way to publish an application to the iOS without a developer license.  If you have a company developer account (different from a personal one) your client can assign you specific permissions.  However, how that is done, is not on topic here at Superuser

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, you can ask your client to log in through Team viewer. Through team viewer your screen will be shared with your client, you both can see what is ongoing on your screen. As password is secure field you can not see password but you will get signed in on your system.